# Get Reports for next 10 days in single database hit

Tags: c#, sql, linq, date

I want to fetch the count for status for the next 10 days in a single database hit using linq in c#.
eg:

```
Table : Task
Coulmun: Id     Status      DueDate
Value     1     New          Jan 1 2013
Value     2     New          Jan 3 2013
Value     3     In Progress  Jan 1 2014
Value     4     Completed    Jun 21 2016
```

Now I want to fetch a report for the Next 10 days from today stating :
No of records which are in each status.
The records count before today date should be part of today date and from tomorrow date it should count of that particular day.

How I can achieve this in a single database hit. I don't want to query DB again n again for 10 times .

Expected result:

```
Date  Jun 20  Jun 21   Jun22 Jun 23 Jun24   Jun 25......
New    2       0        0       0     0        0
InPrg  1       0        0       0     0        0
Complt 0       1        0       0     0        0
```

Solution Tried :

sql query:

```
SELECT count (TaskId) , StatusCode, DueDate  from Task 
where dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, DueDate), 0) BETWEEN CAST('2013/06/08' as DATE) and cast('2013/06/18' as DATE)
--where CONVERT(DATETIME, DueDate)  >CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013/06/08')  and CONVERT(DATETIME, DueDate) < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013/06/18')
GROUP by StatusCode, DueDate
 order by 1 desc 

Result :
(No column name)    StatusCode  DueDate
1   IP  2013-06-08 08:13:36.080
1   IP  2013-06-08 09:49:04.263
1   IP  2013-06-08 10:03:26.550
1   NW  2013-06-08 10:14:11.247
1   IP  2013-06-08 10:33:45.760
1   IP  2013-06-08 20:44:27.427
1   NW  2013-06-09 01:13:54.150
```

Linq Tried :

```
 DateTime startdate;
             DateTime.TryParse("2013/06/08", out startdate);
            DateTime enddate;
             DateTime.TryParse("2013/06/18", out enddate);

 var query = repository.Data
                            .Where(x => x.StatusCode != null
                                && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DueDate) < EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startdate))
                            .GroupBy(p => new
                            {
                                p.StatusCode

                            })
                            .Select(g => new
                            {
                                g.Key.StatusCode,

                                AvailableCpunt = g.Count()
                            }).ToList();


                var result1 = repository.Data
                           .Where(x => x.StatusCode != null
                               && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DueDate) > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startdate) 
                               && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DueDate) < EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(enddate))
                           .GroupBy(p => new
                           {
                               p.StatusCode,
                               p.DueDate

                           })
                           .Select(g => new
                           {
                               StatusCode = g.Key.StatusCode,
                               DueDate = g.Key.DueDate,
                               AvailableCount = g.Count()
                           }).ToList();
```

But again it compare with the time also and hence the results are not correct.
Could some one please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you're posting, please use the preview to check that your post is readable before you post - the tables in your question were incomprehensible before editing.

Comment: Now, what have you tried? And what is the type of `DueDate`? It sounds like you could just use two queries: one for "everything in the past", grouping by status and counting records, and one for "everything between today and 10 days' time", grouping by status and date and counting records. Doing it in one query is trickier, but should still be doable if you can basically say "If the due date is before today, pretend it's today". This sounds like a SQL question really - nothing to do with LINQ particularly.

Comment: I have tried using the group on the status to get the result for the past dates That way it worked and you rightly mentioned we can do for the second part by grouping on the status and date , but when i am trying to do its comparing the time part also as duedate is a datetime column.

DueDate is a DateTime column. 

I tried with the CONVERT(DATETIME, DueDate),  CAST('2013/06/08' as DATE), dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, DueDate), 0), but non of them work , all compare the time also and hence i get so many records.

Could you provide with some snippet , for sql and linq, if possible in 1 query

Comment: Please show exactly what you tried, along with the expected results and actual results.

Comment: Query:
SELECT count (TaskId) , StatusCode, DueDate  from Task 
where dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, DueDate), 0) BETWEEN CAST('2013/06/08' as DATE) and cast('2013/06/18' as DATE)
--where CONVERT(DATETIME, DueDate)  >CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013/06/08')  and CONVERT(DATETIME, DueDate) < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013/06/18')
GROUP by StatusCode, DueDate
 order by 1 desc 

Actual result:
1 IP 2013-06-08 08:13:36.080
1 IP 2013-06-08 09:49:04.263
1 IP 2013-06-08 10:03:26.550
1 NW 2013-06-08 10:14:11.247
1 IP 2013-06-08 10:33:45.760
1 IP 2013-06-08 20:44:27.427
1 NW 2013-06-09 01:13:54.150
and so on...

Comment: I tried with linq the approch you suggested , but it seems its comparing the time also .

Sample:
 DateTime startdate;
                 DateTime.TryParse("2013/06/08", out startdate);
                DateTime enddate;
                 DateTime.TryParse("2013/06/18", out enddate);

Comment: var query = repository.Data
                            .Where(x => x.StatusCode != null
                                && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DueDate) < EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startdate))
                            .GroupBy(p => new
                            {
                                p.StatusCode

                            })
                            .Select(g => new
                            {
                                g.Key.StatusCode,

                                AvailableCpunt = g.Count()
                            }).ToList();

Comment: var result1 = repository.Data
                           .Where(x => x.StatusCode != null
                               && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DueDate) > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(startdate) 
                               && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DueDate) < EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(enddate))
                           .GroupBy(p => new
                           {
                               p.StatusCode,
                               p.DueDate

                           })....cont

Comment: cont...
.Select(g => new
                           {
                               StatusCode = g.Key.StatusCode,
                               DueDate = g.Key.DueDate,
                               AvailableCount = g.Count()
                           }).ToList();

Comment: Please edit all of this into the question - it will be much easier to read that way, and people who can answer shouldn't have to read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should always break the problem in simpler queries to have a clear perspective of What you want. Here you can first categorize every record as day1, day2, ..., day10. Then count every category with grouping on Status.

I think this would do what you want:

```
select
    Status,
    SUM(Day1) Day1, SUM(Day2) Day2 , SUM(Day3) Day3 , SUM(Day4) Day4 , SUM(Day5) Day5,
    SUM(Day6) Day6 , SUM(Day7) Day7 , SUM(Day8) Day8 , SUM(Day9) Day9 , SUM(Day10) Day10
from(
    select
        Status,
        case when DueDate <= cast(GETDATE() as date) then 1 else 0 end Day1,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 1, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day2,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 2, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day3,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 3, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day4,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 4, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day5,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 5, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day6,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 6, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day7,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 7, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day8,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 8, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day9,
        case when DueDate = dateadd(day, 9, cast(GETDATE() as date)) then 1 else 0 end Day10
    from @task
) t
group by Status
```

And here is the linq equivalent:

```
tasks.Select(a => new
{
    Status = a.Status,
    Day1 = a.DueDate <= DateTime.Today ? 1 : 0,
    Day2 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) ? 1 : 0,
    Day3 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(2) ? 1 : 0,
    Day4 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(3) ? 1 : 0,
    Day5 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(4) ? 1 : 0,
    Day6 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(5) ? 1 : 0,
    Day7 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(6) ? 1 : 0,
    Day8 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(7) ? 1 : 0,
    Day9 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(8) ? 1 : 0,
    Day10 = a.DueDate == DateTime.Today.AddDays(9) ? 1 : 0,
}).GroupBy(a => a.Status).Select(a => new
{
    Status = a.Key,
    Day1 = a.Sum(b => b.Day1),
    Day2 = a.Sum(b => b.Day2),
    Day3 = a.Sum(b => b.Day3),
    Day4 = a.Sum(b => b.Day4),
    Day5 = a.Sum(b => b.Day5),
    Day6 = a.Sum(b => b.Day6),
    Day7 = a.Sum(b => b.Day7),
    Day8 = a.Sum(b => b.Day8),
    Day9 = a.Sum(b => b.Day9),
    Day10 = a.Sum(b => b.Day10)
})
```

Comment: Hey ,
Thanks for your help, got an idea what need to be done. However getting an error while i am actually hitting the db.

Error:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any why in which i can make it more dynamic , for 
eg i pass a N(no) from UI for that number of days report is generated , if its N=10 then 10 days , if its N=15 then 15 days ???

Comment: For the error in linq version I would store the DateTime.Today.AddDays(i) in some variables and use it in query. but your next question: it's possible to do that dynamically but with so much trouble, beacuase you want dynamic fileds in your result. I would consider a max value for N and write a query to calculate all that N columns but show only the requested number of days!

Comment: hey , i tried this in the real world today the query is good , but very poor on performance. its taking lot of time as its scanning each and every record . This cant be and optimal solution . instead i tried with the 2 query which was very good on performance but could not achieve in single